# Why my MonoGame simple app is lagging?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I wrote my simple game for Android with MonoGame API.
I touch the app was running with quite good performance but for sure I make simple FPS counter and the resoults was 54-60 fps with does not satisfied me, so i move my fps counter to the MonoGame template to see with part of my code was causing laggs and i found that even almost clear app run with the same speed of 54-60 fps. The problem was not comming from GC because there was no garbage to collect. Is there any option to avoid these lags? Here is the app:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace perf_test
{
    public class FRAPS
    {
        float fps_from;
        int fps;
        public int fps_toshow;

        public float in_Secs;


        public void add_frame()
        {
            fps_from += in_Secs;
            if (fps_from > 1)
            {
                fps_toshow = fps;
                fps = 0;
                fps_from = 0;
            }
            fps++;
        }
    }
    public class numbers
{

    Texture2D[] texture;
    int num1, num2;
    Vector2 pos1, pos2, origin;
    public int number;

    public void load(ContentManager content)
    {
        texture = new Texture2D[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            texture[i] = content.Load<Texture2D>(("" + i));
        }
        num1 = 0;
        num2 = 0;
        number = 22;
        pos1 = new Vector2(250, 50);
        pos2 = new Vector2(270, 50);
        origin = new Vector2(10, 10);
    }

    public void update()
    {

        num1 = 0;
        num2 = 0;
        int nuu = number;
        if (nuu > 10)
        {
             for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
             {
                 if (number >= (i * 10))
                 {
                    num1 = i;
                 }
                else break;
            }
        }
        nuu -= num1 * 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (nuu >= i)
            {
                num2 = i;
            }
            else break;
        }

    }
    public void draw()
    {
        if (number > 9) Game1.spriteBatch.Draw(texture[num1], pos1, origin:     origin);
        Game1.spriteBatch.Draw(texture[num2], pos2, origin: origin);
    }
}

public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    public static SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    FRAPS fraps;
    numbers Numb;
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        fraps = new FRAPS();
        Numb = new numbers();
        graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 480;
        graphics.SupportedOrientations = DisplayOrientation.LandscapeLeft | DisplayOrientation.LandscapeRight;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        Numb.load(Content);
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            Exit();
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        fraps.in_Secs = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        fraps.add_frame();
        Numb.number = fraps.fps_toshow;
        Numb.update();
        Numb.draw();
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

}

Sorry for bad English, I am from Poland.

Comment: What system are you trying to run this on?

Comment: It is Android 4.4.2 (Samsung Galaxy S4 mini GT-I9195)

Comment: Try using an external frame rate counting program like FRAPS (not your class FRAPS, it is strange that you would name it that way...) or any other instead of your own frame counting logic. It may be flawed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set

```
IsFixedTimeStep = false;
```

in your Game1 constructor. XNA/Monogame automatically caps you at 60 FPS.

Comment: It change the fps from 54-60 to 58-62. I don't know what is going on, but it definitely   help a little.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Do You see any garbage making stuff? If not that's all.

Comment: 58-62 is an average of 60. I suspect the fluctuation is an artifact of your framerate computation logic, not an actual behavior of the program. Use an external program to read the framerate.

Comment: is there any, I mean i was looking for some tools for Xamarin and i found only Xamarin Profiler with is for VS Enterprise only